# 2 react-select components on page - one changes value of another

Tags: reactjs, react-select

```
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
...
handleBookKeyWordDropDown (key_wor)  {
    let keys;
    if (key_wor !== null) {
        keys = key_wor;
    } else {
        keys = []
    };
    this.setState({
        currentBook:{
            key_words: keys
        }
    });
}

handleBookBBKDropDown (bbks)  {
    let bks;
    if (bbks !== null) {
        bks = bbks;
    } else {
        bks = []
    };
    this.setState({
        currentBook:{
            bbk: bks
        }
    });
}
...
<div className="row justify-content-end">
    <div className="col-4">
        <label>Ключевые слова:</label>
    </div>
    <div className="col-8">
        <Select
            closeMenuOnSelect={false}
            options={this.state.key_words}
            value={this.state.currentBook.key_words}
            getOptionLabel={ x => x.name}
            getOptionValue={ x => x.id}
            onChange={this.handleBookKeyWordDropDown}
            isMulti
            isSearchable
            placeholder="Выберите ключевые слова"
        />
    </div>
    <div className="row justify-content-end">
        <div className="col-4">
            <label>ББК:</label>
        </div>
        <div className="col-8">
            <Select
                closeMenuOnSelect={false}
                options={this.state.bbk}
                value={this.state.currentBook.bbk}
                getOptionLabel={ x => (x.code+' '+x.description)}
                getOptionValue={ x => x.id}
                onChange={this.handleBookBBKDropDown}
                isMulti
                isSearchable
                placeholder="Выберите ББК"
            />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So the logic is:
initially every one of them has its own default value, which should be changed while changing selected values.

Issue appears when I change anything in any of Select: if I remove any selected value from any Select, other Select's selected values are being removed. But after that if I add something to anything or remove, everything works fine.

[This is how it happens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fyG5.gif)

Have no idea how to deal with it, possibly because of lack of experience with React.

Looking for some help, guys! :)

Comment: Is your second select dependent on the first one? If yes then according to react-select once the default value is changed. the value is reset and then you need to select  a new value. If possible can you share the code onChange event that you are using

Comment: Can you provide full code of this component ?

Comment: @RohanNaik, updated question with onChange methods. Please take a look

Comment: @Piyush, please check, let me know if it is enough to carry on

Comment: How did you declare state variables, currentBook ? PLease show that code too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `currentBook` as an object which store the value of both select fields  and `onChange` you are creating a new object with single select value overriding the second select value

Change your code to this

```
handleBookBBKDropDown (bbks)  {
    let bks;
    if (bbks !== null) {
        bks = bbks;
    } else {
        bks = []
    };
    this.setState({
        currentBook:{
            ...this.state.currentBook, bbk: bks
        }
    });
}

handleBookKeyWordDropDown (key_wor)  {
    let keys;
    if (key_wor !== null) {
        keys = key_wor;
    } else {
        keys = []
    };
    this.setState({
        currentBook:{...this.state.currentBook, 
            key_words: keys
        }
    });
}
```

Here, I am using to [Spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to use previous `currentBook` object and overriding only changed select value

Comment: Great, it worked as I need! And thank you for letting me know about this spread operator, looks like I've missed it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are overriding the state values of other dropdown. You have to keep other state value in current state.

First declare your state like this:

```
this.state = {currentBook:{bbk:[],key_words:[]}}
```

Then do this:

```
 // handleBookKeyWordDropDown

    this.setState({currentBook:{
    ...this.state.currentBook,
                key_words: keys
        }
});

    // handleBookBBKDropDown
    this.setState({currentBook:{
    ...this.state.currentBook
                bbk: bks
        }
    });
```